# EM vector potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, gauge-theory, gauge

We can write the electromagnetic field tensor as
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0     & -E_x/c & -E_y/c & -E_z/c \\
E_x/c & 0      & -B_z   & B_y    \\
E_y/c & B_z    & 0      & -B_x   \\
E_z/c & -B_y   & B_x    & 0
\end{bmatrix} = F^{\mu\nu}.$$
[Erick J. Weinberg, *Classical Solutions in Quantum Field Theory: Solitons and Instantons in High Energy Physics*](http://www.cambridge.org/9780521114639) (p. 43), states:

> For a static solution with vanishing electric fields $F_{0j}$, and hence $A_0 = 0$, [...]

How can this be proven?

Comment: Ca you elaborate please? Is there any difference between $F^{\mu\nu}$ and $F_{0 j}$?

Comment: "An author" seems to refer to: Erick J. Weinberg, _Classical Solutions in Quantum Field Theory: Solitons and Instantons in High Energy Physics_, p. 43.

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): Weinberg's use of the word _hence_ may be a bit misleading. All he means is that it is consistent to _choose_ the temporal gauge $A_0=0$. But it is of course not the only consistent gauge-fixing choice possible.

Comment: @Qmechanic, Weinberg says that for stationary solution $A_0=0$ is it means that the magnetic properties in the tensor fields are zero? Can't we derive that from this equation which is come from the Tensor matrix $F^{\mu\nu}=\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu}-\partial^{\nu}A^{\mu}.$?

Comment: and one more question, in the equation (3.23) Weinberg says equates the energy to zero why is that? Is it due to stationary solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Answer was incorrect. So it was removed

Comment: Can you please show this into the matrix notations with little math  that how $A_0=0$ so the answer will be clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: @dj_mummy There's a very easy MathJax quick reference guide [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).